# Testing behaviour and mocks

Tags: unit-testing, mocking

I'm still not that confident when it comes to write unit tests for more complex methods/classes. My understanding of tdd and unit tests in general is, that you should be able to refactor the implementation of a class / method and have some confidence that you haven't changed it's behaviour

Let me give an example to make things more clear.

```
public class OrderService implements IOrderService
{
    private IItemService itemService;

    public Order create(OrderCreationDto dto)
    {
        Order order = new Order();
        order.addItems(createOrderLines(dto.products));
        return order;
    }

    private Set<OrderLine> createOrderItems(List<ProductDto> products)
    {
        Set<OrderLine> orderLines = new HashSet<>();
        for (ProductDto product : products) {
            Item item = itemService.create(product.id, product.price);
            OrderLine orderLine = new OrderLine();
            orderLine.setItemId(item.id);
            orderLines.add(orderLine);
        }
        return orderLines;
    }
}
```

Basically I'm just creating a new Order from a OrderCreationDto. For each order line I have to use the item service to create a new item first. One of my tests would make sure, that a call to `itemService.create(...)` is made for each order line with certain arguments.

Since each call to `itemService.create(...)` is quite expensive I'd like to refactor the class to create all items in one request .. let's do the changes

```
public class OrderService implements IOrderService
{
    private Set<OrderLine> createOrderItems(List<ProductDto> products)
    {
        Set<OrderLine> orderLines = new HashSet<>();
        BatchItemCreationResponse response = itemService.createAll(products);
        for (ProductDto product : products) {
            Item item = response.get(product.id, product.price);
            ...
        }
        return orderLines;
    }
}
```

Now I've made the changes and my previously written test fails, even though the behaviour of the class has not changed at all.

Am I missing something? Is it something I have to accept the way it is and simply adjust the written test(s)?

Any thoughts are appreciated

Comment: But the implementation of your method changed. Isn't that a good reason for your test to fail?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Am I missing something? Is it something I have to accept the way it is and simply adjust the written test(s)?

No. Yes.

Unit tests *do* change. You've set your test basing on some class to utilize certain contract (`ItemService`). Changing this contract requires you to change the test, as simple as that.

Think about it differently: from tested class client's point of view, nothing changed and behavior is the same (that's good). However, from `ItemService` client point of view, you've intoduced **breaking change** (contract change). Who's the `ItemService` client? In this case, `OrderService` and its tests.

Also, you should consider whether *state verification* (asserting state of `OrderService` products) won't be better fit than *behavior verification* (verifying mock was called). Former one usually makes your tests less fragile to such changes, but neither will make the need of introducing changes to go away.